# Interpreting HR when using tt() function

Tags: r, survival

Assuming non-proportional hazards for karno (and based off p 21):
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf

How does one interpret the HR for karno?

Is the HR = 0.9590 for time = 0, and then for each additional time unit you multiply the HR by 1.0010?
e.g. HR at time = 10 equals 0.9590 x 1.0010^10?
How do you code to estimate that with 95 % C.I.'s?

03/10/2023
Question edited to specify time transform function. I originally assumed this didn't need to be specified and was assumed to be the default interaction with time, but this doesn't seem to be the case as the results have now changed.

````
> library(survival)
> vfit3 <-  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno), data = veteran, tt = function(x, t, ...) x * t)
> summary(vfit3)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno), 
    data = veteran, tt = function(x, t, ...) x * t)

  n= 137, number of events= 128 

                coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
trt        9.748e-02  1.102e+00  1.881e-01  0.518   0.6043    
prior     -9.278e-03  9.908e-01  2.036e-02 -0.456   0.6487    
karno     -4.191e-02  9.590e-01  6.399e-03 -6.549 5.78e-11 ***
tt(karno)  9.936e-05  1.000e+00  4.690e-05  2.119   0.0341 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

          exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
trt          1.1024     0.9071    0.7625    1.5939
prior        0.9908     1.0093    0.9520    1.0311
karno        0.9590     1.0428    0.9470    0.9711
tt(karno)    1.0001     0.9999    1.0000    1.0002

Concordance= 0.713  (se = 0.024 )
Likelihood ratio test= 47.67  on 4 df,   p=1e-09
Wald test            = 49.42  on 4 df,   p=5e-10
Score (logrank) test = 53.07  on 4 df,   p=8e-11
```
````

Comment: Those aren't the results of `vfit3` in the cited reference. You don't show a specific `tt()` function in your call to `coxph()`. The reference used `tt = function(x, t, ...) x * log(t+20)`. What function did you use? Please edit the code in your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that your choice of `tt()` function for these data might not be very wise. With

```
tt = function(x, t, ...) x * t)
```

you are assuming a linear dependence of the `karno` coefficient on time. The worked-through example on page 21 of the cited reference used a logarithmic dependence on time, trying to match (roughly) the shape of the observed dependence in figure 1 of the reference (page 17):

> Early on it has a large negative effect...but by 200 days this has waned and is not much different from zero.

You can now use natural cubic splines in a `tt()` function to let the data tell you an appropriate form. See pages 22-23 of the reference. That might be an even better choice.

Second, it's preferable to do most work with the regression coefficient estimates, which represent log-hazard associations between predictors and outcome, directly. Their covariances are asymptotically multivariate normal, simplifying calculations of confidence intervals. I find the coefficients easier to think about than hazard ratios when there are continuous predictors, as I find it difficult to think about things like "for each additional time unit you multiply the HR by ..." I find it much simpler to think that the log-hazard changes proportionately with changes in the continuous predictor. Exponentiate to get hazard ratios between specific comparisons at the very end.

Third, you have to consider the `karno` coefficient and the `tt(karno)` coefficient together. In this case, the log-hazard relative to baseline (presumably `karno=0`) is:

```
(-0.04191 * karno) +  0.0001 * (karno * t)
```

As suggested above, work directly in this log-hazard scale for your chosen values of `karno` and `t`. Then exponentiate to get hazard ratios.

Fourth, for confidence intervals you need to apply the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables), while working in the scale of coefficient (log-hazard) estimates (with their asymptotic normality). That involves both the variances of the coefficient estimates and the *covariance* between them. Use the `vcov()` function applied to the Cox model object to get those values. Apply the formula to find the 95% confidence intervals (from the assumed normal distribution about the point estimate) in the log-hazard scale, and only then exponentiate to put them into a hazard ratio scale.